# Should `First` always be called after `Open` of a query / `TDataset`?

Tags: delphi, dataset

I am used to always call `First()` when iterating through the results of a query:

```
Qry.Open;
Qry.First;
while not Qry.Eof do
begin
    //do something
    Qry.Next;
end;
```

Is there a reason, that `First()` is not automatically called after `Open()`?

Or asked another way: We use some kind of DB access abstraction classes. Is it a good idea to include the call to `First()` into our `Open()` routine?

Comment: It is not needed, BOF is true when calling `Open`.

Comment: AFAIR opening a dataset (including a query) fetches some data from the database, and `First` is not needed; still I would prefer code that explicitly calls `First` because it is independent of the underlying dataset implementation.

Comment: @whosrdaddy OK, I missed this from the [Delphi documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Eof): "Eof is true when an application: Opens an empty dataset."  -->  So the call to `First` really does not seem to be necessary. I would not have thought so.

Comment: However, I am not sure, but I think we once used a `TDataset` component, that did not work properly without `First()`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are showing the perfect example why `First` is definitely needed: As you don't close the dataset after the iteration, a new call to this code sequence will not really open the dataset. It is still open and the call to `Open` silently does nothing. Thus a `First` is needed to make the iteration work.

Strictly speaking it boils down to what Hilario said: `First` is required before the iteration.

Comment: Actually I only posted the relevant part of the code ;-) But all I read so far seems to suggest, that the call to `First` is recommended (because of the reasons you gave) but **not** technically required, if the code of the question is run once (or `Close` is called before running again).

Answer (score 2):

For most (all) DataSet derivatives, calling First after Open is completely redundant if the dataset was previously closed.

However, if the DataSet had previously been opened without being closed, then the Open will do nothing (as the DataSet is already open), and the First will ensure the DataSet is positioned to the expected position after open (at BOF).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think 'First' needs to be called after the 'Open' of a dataset. 
It needs to be called before the iteration, to make sure it will access all of the records on the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

In the dim distant past (BDE days) I remember reading or hearing that the specs for opening a query did not insist that the query be placed at the beginning of the dataset.  However, all the query component I checked did include a first() somewhere in the code.

I used to subclass a query component to include a first(), but don't now as I don't think it is necessary. All queries I have used open at the first record.

Tracing into the code of a ADO Query open() comes to this bit of code which would appear to leave the dataset at the first position after an open.

```
procedure TCustomADODataSet.InternalFirst;
begin
  if not Recordset.BOF then
  begin
    Recordset.MoveFirst;
    if Recordset.Supports(adMovePrevious) and not Recordset.BOF then
      Recordset.MovePrevious;
  end;
end;
```